# How do I can add new features in Jitsi as required or deemed fit

Tags: jitsi-meet

We have hosted Jitsi for public usage. But there is a request from users to provide few more features as a part of conference mode:

1. Role-Based Privileges:

```
  a) Moderator: All Privileges as administrator
  b) Speaker: Privilege to mute/unmute a participant, share screen, upload the
              presentation
  c) Participant: No privilege unless granted by a Moderator or Speaker
```

2. Conference advance booking/reservations: A user wants to create a pre-named
   conference with a specified list of speaker, moderator, guests and whoever
   is not on the list is participant. Pre-defined user's details will be stored
   on creator account.
3. Authentication: There is a need for dual checking of participant joining a
   conference. The participant needs to checked against already created users
   for the meeting(speakers, moderator, guests and other participants) when they join the conference/meeting and create roles as per information available.
4. Conference Type: There is a need for conference type:

```
    a) Close Conference: This type of conference has privileged conversation so
       only intended people should attend. For that Everyone should be authenticated
       either moderator or participant.
    b) Open Conference: For the open conference, only moderator and speakers should be authenticated and others may or may not need the authentication and can join as a participant.
```

5. For an open conference like classroom/multisession webinar, there is a need for features to switch the presenters.
6. Also, there is need to move users into different room after a common conference discussion. A moderator should have the right to select the user to move the users into predefined rooms.
7. The room creation by a user should be checked against userID that it existing or it's a new room to be created. There is a requirement to bind a room name with a unique ID so that same room name can be allocated to the different conference by the different user may at same or different time frame.

Could anybody let me know how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: You can find the source code and documentation here. https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet

Comment: @truculence It's a diverse code written in many languages. Could you suggest any tool to browse/generate call graph for jitsi source code? it would be a great help to pinpoint the functions where I need to start modification or start inserting the hooks for new modules developed for the purpose.